# Advanced call diverting to know from which number this call is diverted

Tags: caller-id

I have diverted several numbers to  my primary number , I want to know from which number this call be diverted 
Is there any app showing like this call is  diverted from this number ....???,

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Set up a response message...

Use tasker or something on each phone to automatically send a text message saying,

> i just sent a call to you

This way... when the call arrives at the primary phon, So does a text message notification from the original number  :)